# While making a longin singup page in Angular and nodejs i am unable to register users?

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication

I am currently working on a cafe management system and getting trouble while registering my user. Though they are added in the database but not able to login with them and is getting this error. Can anyone help me thorugh this

[error in registering user image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvKWJ.png)

Comment: you need to be clearer, what kind of form are you using? how are you getting data? And please do not use a screenshot of the error but put the full error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.